# After getting success auth code in google api client how to go back and process further execution

Tags: google-api-php-client

api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php` and my code is below.

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('*********');
$client->setClientSecret('*********');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'); 
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

//Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('text/plain');

$data = file_get_contents('document.txt');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
    ));

print_r($createdFile);
?>
```

when i m run this code in browser its ask me for permission and when i accept its redirect to the page where i can get `auth code` but after that how can i come back to my page process further code.

[image]

Please help me to solve this issues. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The user shouldn't input the auth code, the page does it for you as it sends the code through the request, just catch it. In the developers console, there is a field you can enter which says Redirect URI where you can input a web address for the app to redirect you. Remember just to input a non-ip Address for it to work Ex. google.com/index is correct while 45.23.54.74/shcsh/ is not. There you can input the address you need to return to. Try to redirect to a different page than your original code as sometimes the API has troubles with parameters on the Redirect Uri.